# Android - Stop IntentService - Better BroadcastReceiver or static variable?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I my Android app I have an IntentService which does some lengthy operations in the background.
Now what I want to do is to stop the service from a BroadcastReceiver (by stopping I mean setting a flag in the Service to true, so that it ends in the following iteration).
In order to set this flag to true, which of this options would be better:

1) To declare that flag static and modify it directly from the BroadcastReceiver

2) To declare a BroadcastReceiver inside the IntentService and send a broadcast with the flag value set to true

3) Any other way

Thank you

Comment: I did it creating a `public static volatile boolean Running= true;` on your IntentService class, so you could change the value like : YourService.Running = true // if it's running or false if you've stoped it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd avoid static values here. It's not a very good style, altough it would clearly work.
2. That'd do it, but  this might be easier:
3. Send an intent to the service with startService. In that intent set an extra representing your flag.
   In the `onStartCommand` of your Service check if that extra is set with the correct value, and if so update the variable.